# java set of code does not execute

Tags: java, arrays, parameter-passing, response

I have a java code in which parse method returns an array to main method. This array is passed to  OutputFilter method of Parsedanalysis class. But the OutputFilter method is unable to use this array. When I tried to print out myArray[] it works. But nothing else works The output just shows that Build successful. I don't understand it. Could you please provide a solution.

Thanks in advance.

```
 public class Parser {


 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException
 {

 String[] parseOutput;

 parseOutput = parse();
 Parsedanalysis p =new Parsedanalysis();
 p.OutputFilter(parseOutput);

 System.out.println("Output returned array");  //Output Verification//
 for(int i=0;i<parseOutput.length;i++)
 { System.out.println(parseOutput[i]);
 }


}
public synchronized static String[] parse() throws IOException, InterruptedException
{

   {
    String[] output = new String[20];   
    int i=0;
    String command = "cmd /k cd C:\\Program Files\\stanford-parser-2012-11-12 & "                     
        + "set CLASSPATH=.;stanford-parser.jar;stanford-parser-2.0.4-models.jar & "
        + "java -mx100m edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser            edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz data/testsent.txt";         //without typed dependencies    


  Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

     BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new      InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream())); 
        String line = reader.readLine(); 
       System.out.println("Output array");

       for(i=0;!(line=reader.readLine()).isEmpty() && i<20;i++)
         {
            output[i]=line;

              System.out.println("Position"+i+output[i]);

          }  

       //  System.out.println("stopped");
          reader.close();
          return(output);

      }





public class Parsedanalysis {
 static int start = 0;
 static int end;
 static String[] POS,SUB,array;
/**
 *
 * @param myArray
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
public synchronized void OutputFilter(String[] myArray) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{          
     int l=0;                           
 try{

     System.out.println("Parsedanalysis Recieves..");
     for(int k=0;k<myArray.length;k++)
{
    //System.arraycopy(myArray, 0, array, 0, myArray.length);     /*doesn't work beyond this point*/
System.out.println(myArray[k]);
//array[k] = myArray[k];
 }
for(int i=0;i<myArray.length;i++) 
{
   if(myArray[i].contains("(") && myArray[i].contains(")") )
               {
                   System.arraycopy(myArray, i, SUB, l, 1);
               //SUB[l]=myArray[i];
               l++;
               }
    System.out.println(SUB[l]); 

}
```

Comment: It would be *much* easier to read your code if you'd indent it properly. You should also follow normal Java naming conventions. Finally, you've posted a lot of code - I suspect you don't actually need to show us all that code just to demonstrate the problem. You haven't really *described* the problem - you've said that "nothing else works" but not what you expected it to do vs what it actually did.

Comment: Sorry about the indenting. I thought if could give the code as a whole it would be easier to identify the problem. The problem is I wanted to pass the array from main to class ParsedAnalysis where I wanted to get specific array elements under certain conditions.Each element in myArray is a string. In my code I have the output of SUB[l] to be displayed. Even if it doesn't get value it should print something out. But nothing gets displayed. I feel that code doesn't get executed at all.

Answer (score 4):

1. The following condition is invalid:

   `if(myArray[i].contains("(") && myArray[i].contains(")") )`

   The same place in the array cannot hold both "(" and ")" - this condition will always return false!
2. the array SUB is never initialized.

**Remark:**
`for(i=0;!(line=reader.readLine()).isEmpty() && i<20;i++)` will stop on the first empty line in the file, but sometimes there are empty lines and you still want to keep reading, if that is the case you should use `!= null` instead if `! isEmpty()`